# Create select menu in bash

Tags: bash, select

So I am trying to make a little custom management script for my server, but I am running into a problem for creating my menu script with the right results.

I got the following script

```
function config
{

list=''

declare -a programs=("docker" "IdontExist" "pushover" "IdontexistEither")

for program in "${programs[@]}"
do
    #Check if command exists on the server
    if hash $program 2>/dev/null; then
        list="${list} \"${program}\""
    fi
done



title="Config manager"
prompt="Pick an option:"
options=(${list})

echo "$title"
PS3="$prompt "

select opt in "${options[@]}" "Quit"; do
    case "$REPLY" in

    #Dont know how to create this section in a script
    1 ) echo "Update Docker"; break;;
    3 ) echo "Update IdontExist"; break;;
    2 ) echo "Update mytest"; break;;
    4 ) echo "Update IdontExistEither"; break;;

    $(( ${#options[@]}+1 )) ) echo "Goodbye!"; break;;
    *) echo "Invalid option. Try another one.";continue;;
    esac
done

}
```

My list variable will look as follow

```
list: "docker" "pushover"
```

So my options in the script above will not work accordingly. How can I create the options, depending on the list variable?

And I also want to call in certain functions depending on the selected option, for example if somebody choose "docker" I want to call a function named: _docker_config and when its "pushover" I will call a function named _pushover_config How would I also achieve that in the script?

Comment: Why You not try `dialog` program? It makes life so much easier.

Comment: @cdarke: Indeed. I have been merely suggesting alternative, so it was in a comment - not ans answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are testing `$REPLY` instead of `$opt`:

```
select opt in "${options[@]}" "Quit"
do

    if [[ -z $opt ]]; then
        echo "Didn't understand \"$REPLY\" "
        REPLY=
    else
        case "$opt" in

        docker)
            echo "Update Docker"
            break;;
        IdontExist)
            echo "Update IdontExist"
            break;;
        pushover)
            echo "Update mytest"
            break;;
        IdontexistEither)
            echo "Update IdontExistEither"
            break;;
        Quit)
            echo "Goodbye!"
            break;;
        *)
           echo "Invalid option <$opt>. Try another one."
           ;;
        esac
    fi
done
```

If you use `$opt` then you don't need to match the menu numbers (which in your case are variable) with the actual entries (program names) - `select` does that for you.  The only time you need `$REPLY` is when it is invalid (setting `REPLY` to an empty string redisplays the menu on the next iteration).

Not all of the choices in the `case` statement will be valid for every run, but that's OK because `$opt` will only get populated by the valid ones, and the others will not be visible to the user.

You don't need the `continue`, it does that for you by being in a loop.

Edit:

Here is an alternative using an Associative Array instead of a case statement.  It enables the menu and the tests to be dynamic.  In the case shown only two of the options have function, that does not have to be the case, it can be any number (with reason).

```
_docker_config()
{   
    echo "Welcome to docker"
}

_pushover_config()
{   
    echo "Welcome to pushover"
}

# This declares and associative array with the keys being the menu items
# and the values being the functions to be executed.  
# This will have to include all possible programs
declare -A functab=(["Docker"]=_docker_config 
                    ["Pushover"]=_pushover_config)

title="Config manager"
prompt="Pick an option:"

# The options are hard-coded here, of course you will dynamically generate it
# I omitted that for testing purposes
declare -a options=("Docker" "IdontExist" "Pushover" "IdontexistEither")

echo "$title"
PS3="$prompt "

select opt in "${options[@]}" "Quit"
do

    if [[ $opt == "Quit" ]]; then
        echo "Goodbye!"
        break
    fi

    if [[ -z $opt ]]; then
        echo "Didn't understand \"$REPLY\" " >&2
        REPLY=
    else
        # Here we check that the option is in the associative array
        if [[ -z "${functab[$opt]}" ]]
        then
            echo "Invalid option. Try another one." >&2
        else
            # Here we execute the function
            eval ${functab[$opt]}   # See note below
        fi
    fi
done
```

The **eval** is used with caution.  Generally this is a command to avoid because it can be a security issue, however we are checking for valid entries so in this case it is justified.  Just don't over-use it.

Comment: I tried this, and when I corrected the missing ;; in the quit case, it would still fail, no matter what I put in, if I enter 1 it will give me  'Invalid option. Try another one.'

Comment: Sorry about the missing `;;`.  This code works for me, I have done an edit which should indicate what the issue is by displaying `$opt`.  The catch-all `*)` should catch any entry not in the `case` labels, so check things like spelling and upper/lower case against those in `$options`.

Comment: It's working now but I was wondering, would it be possible to have the case be build up dynamically since the options are dynamically created depending on which programs are installed already.

Comment: Yes, sort of.  The case conditions are *patterns*, and you can use variables for the patterns, for example `$prog1)`, but the problem would be that the number of cases is fixed.  An alternative is to use an associative array instead of `case`:  what version of `bash` are you using?  `echo $BASH_VERSION`.  Associative arrays were introduced at Bash 4, if you are using that (or later) then I'll do an example solution for you.

Comment: Another thought, are you just executing the program that is in the menu, or are you doing other processing in the `case`?

Comment: The version I use is 4.2.46(1)-release, what I'm trying to do is make a whole program that I will use to manage my servers. I have a fixed list of programs I will support to install through my own scripts, which will automatically setup all the configs. This part should list the installed programs and allow you to chose which program to update the config file of.

Comment: The case should actually call function which are named relative to the program, so for docker it should call a function named _docker_config and for pushover it will call a function named _pushover_config

Comment: That would be very much appreciated thank you so much!

Comment: Example with associative array added.

Comment: Wish I could up-vote twice, this works just perfectly thank you so much

Comment: @killstreet: glad to help.