# Bash - Multiple choice, user input

Tags: bash

I am quite new in bash and would like to link appropriate choice with profile parameters for that user. Problem is that is not recognize my selection

I have already tried to test but have had syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

```
> echo "Name? Use, alphabetic letter from multiple choice. 
a)Donald
b)Alan 
c)Brian"

  read -p "Insert appropriate letter a, b or c" don ala br

  echo "Perfect" $don 
  echo "Perfect, OK" $ala 
  echo "Perfect, Nice" $br

  case "$dev" 
  echo "OK" 
  esac
```

I would like to hit letter and enter afterwards go to case where define params for the profile.
I have encountered below error:
 syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Comment: A very nice explanation of how to do a Select menu can be found on AskUbuntuu: [How can I create a select menu in a shell script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1705/). Other related are [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/144939) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47186806)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current read command tries to split the input into 3 words, assigning each piece to one of `don`, `ala`, `br`. You just want to read *one* word, and *compare* it to each of `a`, `b`, or `c`. You can do this with a `case` statement:

```
read -p "Insert appropriate letter a, b, or c" choice

case $choice in
  a) echo "Perfect $choice" ;;
  b) echo "Perfect, OK $choice" ;;
  c) echo "Perfect, Nice $choice" ;;
  *) echo "Unrecognized selection: $choice" ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thanks, for hint. Could you also give me directions how to link creation parameters for the account. Perhaps using "if" ?
Mean, selection ended - skip to appropriate values, shaping profile, now

Answer (score 3):

`select` is usually used for command line menus. It normally expects only one answer, but you can tweak it for example in the following way:

```
#! /bin/bash

names=(Donald Alan Brian)
selected=()
PS3='Name? You can select multiple space separated options: '
select name in "${names[@]}" ; do
    for reply in $REPLY ; do
        selected+=(${names[reply - 1]})
    done
    [[ $selected ]] && break
done
echo Selected: "${selected[@]}"
```

Comment: Not quite follow the flow of code. Do we have simplier way on beginning of my way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that will restrict the input to only `a`, `b`, `c`; allowing upper or lower case; waiting for one of those values.

Putting the upper case value in `THIS_SELECTION` and then using it in a case statement:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Name? Use, alphabetic letter from multiple choice. 
    a)Donald
    b)Alan 
    c)Brian"

THIS_SELECTION=
until [ "${THIS_SELECTION^}" == "A" ] || [ "${THIS_SELECTION^}" == "B" ] || [ "${THIS_SELECTION^}" == "C" ]; do
    read -n1 -p "Insert appropriate letter a, b or c: "  THIS_SELECTION
    THIS_SELECTION=${THIS_SELECTION^}
    echo;
done 

case "${THIS_SELECTION}" in
    A) echo A Donald ;;
    B) echo B Alan ;;
    C) echo C Brian ;;
    *) echo other ;;
esac
```